# How can I display the elements of stack in an increasing order?

Tags: c++, stack

Using C++, I need to make a program wherein the user inputs 5 numbers then it will be put in a stack in ascending order. Kindly help me what to correct in my code and what should I do. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<int> sNum;
    stack<int> ascend;
    int A, B = 0;

    for (int x=1; x<=5; x++){
        cout<<"Enter a number: ";
        cin>>A;
        sNum.push(A);

        if (A>B){
            B = A;
            ascend.push(B);
        }
    }
    for(int y=1; y<=5; y++){
        cout<<ascend[y]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is input, output and expected output?

Comment: You can only access the top element of a stack. (A stack is not a sequence.)

Comment: the input will be from the user, and the expected output would be in ascending order of the numbers the user input

Comment: use a priority_queue

Comment: You need to move elements between the stacks in order to insert a new element at the correct position.

Comment: Starting with two empty stacks, `s` and `tmp`, you repeatedly do the following. (1) Read `value` from the user. (2) While `s` is not empty AND the top of the `s` stack is less than `value`, push the current top of `s` onto `tmp`, then pop `s`. (3) Push `value` on to `s` . (4) While `tmp` is not empty, push the current top of `tmp` on to `s`, then pop `tmp`. That's it. Repeat those for however many iterations you desire. When done `s` will contain all your input in pop-ascending order. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Stack is not correct data structure to use in this problem since you can only access the top element.

You can use `std::vector` as data structure and `std::sort` to sort the vector after user inputs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for std::sort
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> sNum;
    int A;

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        cout<<"Enter a number: ";
        cin >> A;
        sNum.push_back(A);
    }
    std::sort(sNum.begin(),sNum.end());
    for(auto& x : sNum) // Use range-based loop for containers 
        cout<< x <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right, std::stack is the wrong data structure to use. Another option is to use std::map which itself maintains a sorted order.